# How to show that if $H \leq G$ and $H$ is the only subgroup of $G$ of order n than $ H\trianglelefteq G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $H$ is the only subgroup of $G$ of the order $n$.  How would I prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?  I was thinking of using the fact that $|gHg^{-1}| = |H|$, but I did not get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with $|gHg^{-1}| = |H|$.  You can prove that the map $\phi:G \rightarrow G$ defined by $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$ for any $g \in G$.  So what can we say about the restriction of $\phi$ to any subgroup of $G$?